# How to commit .m2 Maven repository to SVN

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, svn, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Maven and integrating Selenium testng suites with Maven and Jenkins along with SVn as repository. However I am getting below error when i trigger a target in Jenkins.

"[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Network is unreachable -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
"

Below is my Maven pom.xml structure

```
<properties>
    <suiteXmlFile>webtest.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.28.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I am not sure if i have to commit .m2 file to SVN as well? or how should i configure in SVN repository and in Jenkins? Both My jenkins and SVN repository are On Server.

Comment: Never commit `$HOME/.m2/`  into svn ...Apart from that you have network issue to access maven central `Network is unreachable -> [He....`...you should solve this first...either start using a repository manager or by using a proxy...

Comment: .m2 is not something which you need to commit to SVN. the problem here is the difficulty in getting the dependency.

Comment: How shall i implement or add Proxy or repository Manager?

Comment: @Ashu123 - you would read the Maven docs: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a proxy setup for Internet connection. The proxy is blocking the direct access to mvn repository in your target machines. You have to configure . proxy server in settings.xml (located at root of .m2 directory). Normally , an artifactory serves the artifact as a proxy mvn repo.  Consult with the IT team/Dev team for getting requisite settings.